# Create Subquery Select for COUNT with JOIN inside the subquery

Tags: sql, join, subquery

Have this COUNT subquery but I can't get the syntax to work .

```
    SELECT products.client_id,
       clients.name AS client_name,
       cars.vin,
       cars.make,  
    cars.model
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM manheim_auction_listings AS listings_sub
        JOIN products ON 
          manheim_auction_listings.product_id  = products.id 
        JOIN product_purchases ON
           products.current_product_purchase_id = product_purchases.id 
       WHERE listings_sub.car_id = manheim_auction_listings.car_id AND                      
          listings_sub.id <> manheim_auction_listings.id and         
          manheim_auction_listings.product_purchase_id = 
          product_purchases.id) as previous_auction_count 
      FROM manheim_auction_listings
      JOIN cars ON 
      cars.id = manheim_auction_listings.car_id .....
```

The (SELECT COUNT(*) will not pass syntax with the JOIN's I Need to get the right count.

Comment: Tips of how to ask question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve What are you trying to accomplish here?  What's your query is doing?  Telling what your query is trying to do helps.

Comment: Your subquery in a select statement is poor form.  Need to know what you're trying to accomplish here to help further though...all I can tell you now is your logic that you've approached this with is off (to the point where I can't quite tell what you are trying to accomplish here).  Read link from Eric...if you tell us what you are trying and expect to happen, we can give you better direction.  Perhaps as a better thought...subqueries are best in the from clause...write a query that gets the count by key, then join that in your from clause.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `GROUP BY` in your inner query.

```
WHERE listings_sub.car_id = manheim_auction_listings.car_id AND                      
      listings_sub.id <> manheim_auction_listings.id and         
      manheim_auction_listings.product_purchase_id = 
      product_purchases.id
      GROUP BY <list_of_column(s)>
```

Also, there are couple more syntax error(s)

You are missing comma `,` just after `cars.model` column ***MUST*** be separated by `,`.

```
 cars.model
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM manheim_auction_listings AS listings_sub
```

Comment: I don't believe that would help since this is a subquery. the error is: Unknown column 'manheim_auction_listings.product_id' in 'on clause'. there is additional info on the Select after the ..... I Just left it off as it does have some ORDER BY for the original SELECT.

Comment: yes it instantly gives me a error on the next JOIN line "JOIN cars ON 
      cars.id = manheim_auction_listings.car_id" and references incorrect syntax

Comment: @RyanNevesNevesMedia You have many syntax error(s) go through my updated post